# Is it possible to send screenshots to Slack from a Ruby-Watir test?

Tags: ruby, slack, watir

I currently have a Slack webhook that allows me to post results from my script to Slack.

I was just wondering if it's possible to post a screenshot to Slack? I already save screenshots to my local directory as part of the test using the screen capture function. Is there anyway to send those to Slack instead?

Sample of my code:

```
require 'watir'
require_relative 'regression_config.rb'
require 'date'
require 'faker'
require 'slack-notifier'  # SLACK




screenCapture(browser,"Origination Portal - Login",test_id)   # Screen shot sent locally to drive
   

# Slack functions
notifier = Slack::Notifier.new "https://hooks.slack.com/services/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" # Slack webhook

single_message = ">>>>>Auto Regression was not run. Possible login / environment issue<<<<<"

notifier.ping single_message # Post to Slack
```